# I could not understand way its giving error "Missing method body, or declare abstract"

Tags: android, android-studio, class, retrofit, retrofit2

```
package com.example.rvj;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Url;

public class RetrofitAPI {
   @GET
    Call<NewsModal> getAllNews(@Url String url);

   @GET
    Call<NewsModal>getNewsByCategory(@Url String url);
}
```

There should be no error,and this code is has no error in others code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: use interface instead of class. make it like `public interface RetrofitAPI`

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit methods should be within an interface, not a class!
Give this a try:

```
package com.example.rvj;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Url;

public interface RetrofitAPI {
   @GET
   Call<NewsModal> getAllNews(@Url String url);

   @GET
   Call<NewsModal>getNewsByCategory(@Url String url);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much i could not detect my silly mistake